# Asp.net Identity + Unit of Work: Getting duplicated entries

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am using the newest version of ASP.NET Identity, using the sample project as a base template.
My changes are simple: Adding a FIRM Properyt to the application user.

Thus, the application User looks like this:

```
   public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the firm.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The firm.
        /// </value>
        public virtual Firm Firm { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generates the user identity asynchronous.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="manager">The manager.</param>
        /// <returns>A claims identity</returns>
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            //// Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            //// Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
```

Also, I do have a Unit Of Work implented, which is responsible for Firm and other entities.

```
 /// <summary>
    /// This contains a Unit of Work pattern Implementation. Provides access to all Elements used in this Application.
    /// </summary>
    public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable, IUnitOfWork
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The database context
        /// </summary>
        private PriorityDBContext dbContext = new PriorityDBContext();

        public UnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
        {
            this.dbContext = (PriorityDBContext)ApplicationDbContext;
        }

        private GenericRepository<Firm> firmRepository;

        public IGenericRepository<Firm> FirmRepository
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.firmRepository == null)
                {
                    this.firmRepository = new GenericRepository<Firm>(this.dbContext);
                }

                return this.firmRepository;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now to my problem: I have an Account Controller, which can create new Users (among other things). When a new User is created, the Firm is silently doubled. E.g. I had a Firm called "Example1" in the database before. Now I create a new User and suddenly the Database contains "Example1" two times.
As far I can tell, the root cause is that Asp.net Identity uses one DbContext, my UnitOfWork another. I am unsure why, I tried to set up Ninject in a way that the same DbContext is used in all parts. But it simply have enormous problems getting the same db Context into the UserManager and the unit of work :(

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
/// <summary>
/// The Unit of Work
/// </summary>
private IUnitOfWork uoW;

/// <summary>
/// The _user manager
/// </summary>
private ApplicationUserManager userManager;

public AccountController(IUnitOfWork uow)
{
    this.uoW = uow;
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the user manager.
/// </summary>
/// <value>
/// The user manager.
/// </value>
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        if (this.userManager == null)
        {
            this.userManager =  HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }

        return this.userManager;
    }

    private set
    {
        this.userManager = value;
    }
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    bool success = true;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
                var firm = this.uoW.FirmRepository.GetRaw().Where(f => f.FirmName == newUser.Firm).First();
                var user = new ApplicationUser { FirstName = newUser.FirstName, LastName = newUser.LastName, Email = newUser.Email, UserName = newUser.Email, PreferredLanguage = newUser.Language, Firm = firm };

                var password = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var result = await this.UserManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    this.logger.Info("Created user for {0} successfully", newUser.Email);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Ninject, registering the Bindings:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    /// loading the ApplicationDbContext here because the UserManager uses it from the OwinContext and if the
    /// Unit of Work defines it's own DBContext, bad things happen, e.g. duplicated objects when working with users AND our own pocos here.
    kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().WithConstructorArgument("dbContext", ninjectContext => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>());
    kernel.Bind<IGenericRepository<Firm>>().To<GenericRepository<Firm>>();
    //kernel.Bind<ApplicationUserManager>().To(HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>());
}
```

The ApplicationUserManager:

```
  public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
            : base(store)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
            //// Konfigurieren der Überprüfungslogik für Benutzernamen.
            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };

            // snipped

            return manager;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @tschmit007 Yes, that is definitely the root problem. But I am totally at a loss how to resolve that problem? I tried using the Context from the Usermanager (because you cannot inject a DbContext), but that does not work :(

Comment: Why has CreateAsync to be modified?